# ASP.NET Core, how to secure endpoint against brute force attack

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-core, flutter

I creatad an API with Login() endpoint. This API is being consumed by mobile application. 
I am about to publish that app to Google Play store.
My fear is related to security.
I could implement something like captcha in my mobile app but it would not stop attacker before sending request from for ex. curl.
How to handle it?

Comment: API endpoints shouldn't have login method. The common use case is to use an OpenID/OAuth provider, redirect the user there on login, so he can enter his data at his trustworthy provider (rather than putting his credentials into the app) and in exchange gets an authentication token which is submitted to the pages. Other than that, ASP.NET Core Identity has a mechanism to lock accounts for some time after the wrong password has been entered

Comment: I cant use OpenID/OAuth, since my users authenticates themselves in AD.

Comment: You shouldn't expose AD (directly or indirectly) to the public or use it as authentication scheme, because AD doesn't have any mechanisms for protecting against bruteforcing (and lockouts can't be applied for AD, since if you would lockout an account the user couldn't use the desktop/laptops to loginto the domain). I'd suggest you use Azure AD, it acts as OpenID provider and it can AD can be set in federation mode to sync with your Azure AD (so if a user changes his password it will be synced with Azure AD within a couple of minutes)

Comment: For that reason, ASP.NET Core identity doesn't offer an AD provider for authentication. For Azure AD/AD sync, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity

Comment: I knew that it is not a good idea, but did not know why. Now it is clearer.

Comment: What do you think about this https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/aad_oauth#-readme-tab-